# How can I remove a Google internet account when the Google account has been closed?

Tags: gmail, ical

I recently closed my google account and now I would like to remove the corresponding account in iCal which was linked to my google account.

When I go to "Internet Accounts" and then click on the account I want removed on the left and click the `-` I get the error

> Internet accounts preferences can't connect to gmail account

And I can't verify my account because the google account has been closed.

Is there a way to force the removal?

Comment: I would say wrong order. First remove account from Mac. Then go to Google and cancel it there.

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks but it it is too late for that. As noted in the question I have already canceled the google account.

Comment: right, which is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Not clear how you closed and what?  is it by going to your Google account then closing the gmail or closing the Google account. You Mac should give you errors now since the account no longer exists.

Comment: It is giving me errors. I closed my gmail account by going to gmail.com and clicking `delete` account.

Comment: Still asking you for the connection? do you have it in the iCloud, iCloud keychain ect..